# Where can I find a dataset for Chinese characters to back an app I want to write?

Tags: database

I've been spending a lot of time learning chinese, and have some ideas for apps that would make this complicated process easier.

I'm looking for datasets (ideally free) that I can use to back an app I want to write.

The dataset should have definitions, character ranks, frequency data, radical composition data etc.

An example of an existing app is http://www.hanzicraft.com/character/%E5%AE%89

Where does one obtain such data?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: unicode.org is a good starting place.

Comment: I don't see anything of this nature on unicode.org!!

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/ Choose Unihan.zip

Comment: 倪阔乐 I think you may not be understanding the question properly.

Comment: I think you may not understand datasets properly.

Comment: That could be. Could you point to the files that contain "definitions, character ranks, frequency data, radical composition data etc."?

Comment: Download. It contains 8 text files, e.g. Unihan_Readings.txt. Each line represents data associated with different code points, like U+6211, identifying Unicode characters, in this case Chinese characters. What U+6211 stands for can be found via a simple HTML page, and it defines 我. The entries for U+6211: kCantonese: ngo5; kDefinition: our, us, i, me, my, we; kHangul: 아; kHanyuPinyin: wǒ; kMandarin: wǒ; and a few more. The other files contain additional data, like Unihan_DictionaryLikeData.txt: kTotalStrokes: 7. This is a relational database, and you need to adapt it to your preferred format.

Comment: So when you have built your basic SQL database with unicode code points as base, you can add additional data from CEDICT and other sources. Bottom line is, you need to do some work yourself to extract the data into the format you want. By necessity, you will need unicode for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some free databases that may be useful to you:

- [CC-CEDICT](https://cc-cedict.org/wiki/): high quality user-created  dictionary released under a Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 License
- [SUBTLEX-CH](http://crr.ugent.be/programs-data/subtitle-frequencies/subtlex-ch): Chinese word and character frequencies based on film and television show subtitles
- [Wikimedia Commons Chinese character decomposition database](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Chinese_characters_decomposition)

Answer (score 2):

That website is made with the following resources that you can find in the [FAQ](http://www.hanzicraft.com/about) section:

> Where does the data come from?
>
> HanziCraft would not exist without the massive amounts of work already
>   done by other people & researchers.
>
> - [Leiden University Weibo Corpus Data](http://lwc.daanvanesch.nl/)
> - [Gavin Grover's Decomposition Data](http://cjkdecomp.codeplex.com/)
> - [CC-CEDICT](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=cc-cedict)
> - [Junda's Character Frequency Data](http://lingua.mtsu.edu/chinese-computing/)

Answer (score 0):

I found sources for characters, definitions, and stroke order to build a [set of flash cards](https://donkirkby.github.io/donkirkby-old/ChineseVocabulary). I listed [several sources](https://donkirkby.github.io/donkirkby-old/ChineseSources) on the project web site.

Comment: The lnks are fixed now, @maritsm. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

汉字分解。 Decomposition of the Chinese Character  火 huǒ  ‘fire’

丷  bā eight,
人  rén man,

丷人

Chinese, Character, Breakdown, Decomposition, Analysis, Strokes, Language, Dictionary, Textbook, Break Down, Split, Analyze, Decompose, Learn, Memorize, Broken Down

More information: http://www.lulu.com/content/e-book/the-chinese-character-decomposition-guidance/18847104 and http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/polina985

Answer (score 0):

汉字分解。 Decomposition of the Chinese Character  能  néng     ‘be able to’

厶  sī  private,
⺝  yuè    moon,
冂  jiōng  down box,
二  èr  two,
匕  bǐ  spoon,
丿  piě  slash,
乚  yǐ  second,
匕  bǐ  spoon,

厶⺝ 冂 二 匕丿乚匕

Chinese, Character, Breakdown, Decomposition, Analysis, Strokes, Language, Dictionary, Textbook, Break Down, Split, Analyze, Decompose, Learn, Memorize, Broken Down

More information: http://www.lulu.com/content/e-book/the-chinese-character-decomposition-guidance/18847104 and http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/polina985